# setting Google map type to MAP_TYPE_HYBRID on launch of app, shows MAP_TYPE_NORMAL for fraction of seconds and then switches to MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google maps in my android project. Here i want to show Hybrid type of map by default.  So on launch of the app, I have set the map type as MAP_TYPE_HYBRID. But it shows MAP_TYPE_NORMAL for fraction of seconds and then switches to MAP_TYPE_HYBRID. Can any one help me about this? or can i set the map type in xml? Thanks.

Comment: where do you set this? Please post some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do if you set the parameter to the fragment being the map:
I'm copying here all the accepted parameters, just FYI:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  map:cameraBearing="112.5"
  map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
  map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"
  map:cameraTilt="30"
  map:cameraZoom="13"
  map:mapType="hybrid"
  map:uiCompass="false"
  map:uiRotateGestures="true"
  map:uiScrollGestures="false"
  map:uiTiltGestures="true"
  map:uiZoomControls="false"
  map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I will try this soon and let you know.